# Workflow Not Being Published to Site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

I created a workflow in Sharepoint Designer 2013 and then hit the Publish button in the top left. It brings up the loading bar, it does all the things it needs to, and then finishes without an issue. However, the workflow cannot be found on the site. When I go to Site Contents -> Site Workflows, it isn't there. Am I looking in the wrong place or is it not being properly published.

I have tried clearing the cache and publishing again but that didn't change anything. Other than that, I haven't seen any suggestions for fixing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 types of workflows, site workflows and list workflows. Site workflows will be visible where you describe.

I am assuming you had created a list workflow which would show up under the Workflow settings of the list/library.

If the start parameters for this workflow are on item creation or item change, then there is nothing for the user to do to start the workflow, it will happen automatically. If the start option for this workflow is to be manually initiated by the user, they will get to it via the ribbon or in the item's context menu.

Comment: Ah. There it is. How would I put this somewhere that a user could access it though?

Comment: is it a manually initiated workflow?

Comment: I made it in Designer if that's what you mean.